# Remove specific words from dataframe column in R

Tags: r, string

I want to remove specific words from dataframe column.
I tried below code

```
word_to_remove=c("Chat Started:","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","TeamAgent")
df['text']=gsub(paste(word_to_remove,collapse='|'),"",df['text'])
```

But I'm getting error, calloc could not allocate memory, data hardly consists 60 rows.
When applying on string it's working fine but when I apply it on dataframe getting this error, any alternate way of doing it or how we can fix this error.

Comment: Are you certain that `words_to_remove` in your actual script only has 5 items?

Comment: Try : `df[['text']]=gsub(paste(word_to_remove,collapse='|'),"",df[['text']])`

Comment: @Tim- Yes, Tim.

Comment: @Ronak- I tried the way you suggested but its' been running from more than 5 mins now, I suspect it's also going to throw same error "calloc could not allocate memory"

Comment: Did you try restarting your R session and trying again?

Comment: Yes, multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df$text=gsub(paste(word_to_remove,collapse='|'),"",df$text)
```